# Numerous GET requests in ASP.NET MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I just created new ASP.NET MVC 4 app, and while inspecting network traffic, I noticed numerous of GET requests.

This is a screenshot of traffic:
http://pokit.org/get/?59050db88c766d3310943b4bbe391de2.jpg

These are request headers http://pokit.org/get/?80e8e84398dfc838938438ec33e5dd92.jpg

So, request occurs every 6 seconds. Could this happen because I installed DevExpress (doesn't make any sense).
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this is just an activity related to the browserLink, see http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink. This is Visual Studio feature, to sync your css, inspect code and so.

There can be some requests, when in debug mode, because browserLink is doing it's job.

Comment: Not a guess, that's what it is.

Comment: There is no way I could know that :D Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This is very annoying at sometimes. 
So [there](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx) is a documentation about this feature.

And how to disable it - just uncheck it.

[image]